# Exchange api call to ResolveName returns multiple items

Tags: c#, exchange-server

We are using the exchange api to fetch items and we use the call:

```
PropertySet psPropSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
service.ResolveName(userPhotoRequestModel.LoginId, ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly, true, psPropSet);
```

We are giving it the NTLogin as the value to search for. What we are finding is that sometimes, we get back more than on item in the NameResolutionCollection. You would think that, with using an NTLogin, that we would get an exact match and only 1 item in the collection. But sometimes we get 2. Has anyone else seen something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ResolveName does partial matches eg if I have two users bsmith and bsmith1 and I do a resolveName on bsmith then both of these entries will be returned as they both match what is being resolved.

ResolveName using ANR https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx so if you want to an exact match all you should need to do is prefix the NTLogin with = eg

```
service.ResolveName("=mylogin", ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly, true, psPropSet);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It worked great and thanks for the link on the ANR.